# sdcli format - providing custom configuration file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, code-formatting

I'm trying to format a PLSQL code using "sdcli format" command line tool from SQL developer.

I would like to provide a custom configuration file in order to customize the output.

The idea is to create my "perfect setting" from the GUI, then exporting it into a file and re-using this exported file while invoking sdcli.

Is it possbible?

Answer (score 2):

the new [SQLCL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) supports the feature you are describing.

```
SQLcl: Release 17.4.0 Production on Tue Feb 20 16:08:22 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options


FORMAT
---------

FORMAT BUFFER - formats the script in the SQLcl Buffer
FORMAT RULES <filename> - Loads SQLDeveloper Formatter rules file to formatter.
FORMAT FILE <input_file> <output_file>

Format used is default or for SQLcl can be chosen by setting an environmental variable
pointing to a SQLDeveloper export (.xml) of formatter options.
The variable is called SQLFORMATPATH
In SQLDeveloper the format options are the default chosen in the preferences.

SQL>
```

see https://community.oracle.com/thread/4110977 for a script that can processed entire directories of files